# How to init type interface?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new of Typescript.
now facing the difficult problem for me.

I want to init Typescript interface field of WebSocketSubjectConfig's 「WebSocketCtor」 field in Rxjs , but i don't know how to do it.

my developing environment is 
npm     = 「5.6.0」 
node    = 「8.11.1」
Angular = 「6.0.3」 
rxjs    = 「6.2.0」

below is my code

```
/** setting of websocket */
protected getWebsocketConfig(url:string) : WebSocketSubjectConfig<any>{
    return {
                url: url,
                /*
                I can't init this field. how to init ?
                WebSocketCtor: {
                    WebSocket:new WebSocket(url);
                },
                */
                openObserver: {
                    next: (_e: Event) => {
                        console.log("Websocket is open!!!!");
                        console.dir(_e);
                    }
                },
                closeObserver: {
                    next: (_e: CloseEvent) => {
                        console.log("Websocket is close !!!!")
                    }
                },
           };
}
```

I thought WebSocketSubject's unsubscribe method close websocket connection.
but It's look like don't work.
I think if close the websocket connection ,  need to implement the 「WebsocketCtor」 and call the Websocket's close method.

the WebSocketSubjectConfig interface is below

```
export interface WebSocketSubjectConfig {
    ・・・
    openObserver?: NextObserver;
    closeObserver?: NextObserver;
    WebSocketCtor?: {
        new (url: string, protocols?: string | string[]): WebSocket;
    };
}
```

thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new` keyword in an type defines that the type should have a constructor matching that signature. Therefore, `WebSocketCtor` needs to be an object with a constructor that takes a `string` and an optional `string | string[]`, and returns a `WebSocket` object. An object that fits this bill is the [`WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/WebSocket) class/constructor itself!

```
protected getWebsocketConfig(url:string) : WebSocketSubjectConfig<any>{
    return {
                url: url,
                WebSocketCtor: WebSocket,
                openObserver: {
                    next: (_e: Event) => {
                        console.log("Websocket is open!!!!");
                        console.dir(_e);
                    }
                },
                closeObserver: {
                    next: (_e: CloseEvent) => {
                        console.log("Websocket is close !!!!")
                    }
                },
           };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
protected getWebsocketConfig(url: string): WebSocketSubjectConfig<any> {
        return {
            url: url,
            WebSocketCtor: WebSocket, // <-- this
            openObserver: {
                next: (_e: Event) => {
                    console.log("Websocket is open!!!!");
                    console.dir(_e);
                }
            },
            closeObserver: {
                next: (_e: CloseEvent) => {
                    console.log("Websocket is close !!!!")
                }
            },
        };
    }
```